# getView() is invoked too late

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

I built a custom adapter in order to correctly display some data in a list view. In *onContextItemSelected*() the dataset is changed and I call *notifyDataSetChanged*() to update the list view. Apparently the adapter's *getView*() method only gets invoked **after** *onContextItemSelected*() terminated.

1. Why?
2. In *contextItemSelected()* I call the method *editLanguage()* that needs to access a button which is supposed to be inflated earlier by *getView()*. As *getView()* is called "too late" i get a NullpointerException.

The button is inflated in "getView" which should be invoked by "notifyDataSetChanged".

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)   item.getMenuInfo();
   languageItem selectedLanguage = languages.get((int) info.id);
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case EDIT: 
      languages.get((int) info.id).setSelected(true); 
      adapter.update(languages); 
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call getView() of the adapter!
      editLanguage(selectedLanguage); // access a button that was inflated by getView()
//...


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
//...         
switch(getItemViewType(position)) {
  case DEFAULT_LINE:
   //...
   break;
  case EDIT_LINE: 
   convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.language_row_edit, null); // contains button bu_language_change
   viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bu_language_change);
   break;
  //...
```

I get null when trying to access the button (bu_language_change).

```
private void editLanguage(final LanguageItem languageToEdit) {

Button editButtonConfirm = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bu_language_change); // null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notifyDataSetChanged does NOT force adapter to call sequence of getView method instantly. It rather tells that it should be refreshed and it happens asynchronously. If you want to achieve that goal you mentioned I have 2 ideas:

1. Add `bu_language_change Button` to your view from `DEFAULT_LINE` with visibility level `View.GONE` then in your `EDIT_LINE` you change visibility `View.VISIBLE`. `View.GONE` makes your layout to behave as it has no such child(bu_language_change Button).
2. Somehow notify from getView() method that inflating view has been done, and call `editLanguage` method. But it's a bad idea. `Romain Guy` [in here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/TErt3iL-RZQ/-u9vha3_zCsJ) says:

> ... getView() is not guaranteed to be called exactly 
>   once per item ...

Or call this `editLanguage` method from the body of `getView` method, that would have solved your problem.

I recommend to watch Google I/O about ListViews. [It's over here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution works for me. Actually I cannot imagine that this hack is the only good solution. Assuming I have three completely different row types. It would be ugly to implement all views in one .xml file and just changing their visibility. Furthermore calling editLanguage from the Adapter infringes the SoD principle. Any suggestions?